# wpf: change a style DataTrigger to a ControlTemplate DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, controltemplate, datatrigger

I have a large ControlTemplate for a ToggleButton. I am trying to add a data trigger with no succes.

I have however manged to add it using a style, as shown below:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="toggleBtnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=myProperty}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="IS TRUE"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=myProperty}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="IS FALSE"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ToggleButton Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="toggleBroadcast" Click="Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" Margin="180,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource toggleBtnStyle}"/>
```

Is there a way to add this to a Control Template? I have the following control template which is triggered on the IsChecked Property of the ToggleButton, I am trying to change it to the DataTrigger in the Style above, without success.

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ClipBoardButton1" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black" >
            <Grid>
                <Border x:Name="BorderUp" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1" Background="Blue"/>
                <Border x:Name="BorderDown" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1" Opacity="0" Background="Aqua"/>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Contents" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="ButtonDownTimeLine">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderDown" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.05" Value="1"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Contents" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                    <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.025" Value="0.5,0.5,0,0"/>
                </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="ButtonUpTimeLine">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderDown" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="0"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Contents" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                    <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ButtonDownTimeLine}"/>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ButtonUpTimeLine}"/>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

To be clear:

1. I want to use a DataTrigger on myProperty
2. Have the same Trigger action as the IsChecked action currently. (Implement the Storyboards)

I have tried lots of different things and searched through so many posts, but cant find the answer I am seeking.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, you are using *a* style to apply this `Template` to `ToggleButton`. If not, create a default style for `ToggleButton` and Set `Template` property to your `ControlTemplate`

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ClipBoardButton1}" />
</Style>
```

And, coming to your problem around using DataTriggers, I wouldn't add `DataTriggers` to `ControlTemplate`, because, think about this scenario, what happens when you want to use this same template at a different place where the property name is different (not `myProperty`)?

To achieve what you are trying, you can update your `Trigger` in the `ControlTemplate` to the following:

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="IS TRUE" />
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ButtonDownTimeLine}"/>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ButtonUpTimeLine}"/>
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="IS FALSE"></Setter>
</Trigger>
```

and Bind `IsChecked` property of `ToggleButton` to your `myProperty`

```
<ToggleButton Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              x:Name="toggleBroadcast" 
              Click="Button_Click" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Width="133" Margin="180,0,0,0" 
              IsChecked="{Binding myProperty}"/>
```

**UPDATE**

Replace your trigger in `ControlTemplate` with:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding myProperty}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ButtonDownTimeLine}"/>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ButtonUpTimeLine}"/>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks thats almnost what I want, but myProperty is being set to IsChecked, but really i need IsChecked set to myProperty. I need to set the trigger in the ControlTemplate when myProperty changes in the code behind

Comment: @Andy Updated answer to have `DataTrigger` in `ControlTemplate`, I have tested this and seem to be working!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the control template with in the style. as below. I hope this helps

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="toggleBtnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=myProperty}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="IS TRUE"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=myProperty}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="IS FALSE"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black" >
                        <Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="BorderUp" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1" Background="Blue"/>
                            <Border x:Name="BorderDown" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1" Opacity="0" Background="Aqua"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Contents" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="ButtonDownTimeLine">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderDown" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.05" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Contents" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.025" Value="0.5,0.5,0,0"/>
                            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="ButtonUpTimeLine">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderDown" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Contents" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ButtonDownTimeLine}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ButtonUpTimeLine}"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. But what i need is the ControlTemplate trigger to be based on myProperty. So when myProperty is changed in the code behind the Storyboard is started. Right now its always started on the IsChecked event, I need it to start when myProperty is changed.